# What does power of '+' in $\hat{\beta}_j=\operatorname {sign} (\hat{\beta^0_j})(|\hat{\beta^0_j}|-\gamma)^+$means?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I encountered the following equation in a paper.
$$\hat{\beta}_j=\operatorname {sign} (\hat{\beta^0_j})(|\hat{\beta^0_j}|-\gamma)^+$$

What does the power of '+' mean? The paper can be viewed at:
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf

Comment: Could you give a reference to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Typically $\alpha^+$ means $\max \{\alpha,0\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

The notation is usually not meant to be "the power of $+$" but rather "the positive part". For a function $f(t)$, one has
$$
f^+(t)=\max\{f(t),0\}.
$$